# Is it possible to train tensorflow on android?

Tags: android, tensorflow

It seems no C++ API to train tensorflow graph and save to pb.So,any way to do that on Android platform? can I build tensorflow workspace with python API on Android devices?

Answer (score 0):

Since you would need to install tensorflow on your android device and then run a python script on your android device, I highly doubt that this is possible.
Also, since training is always relatively resource intensive, it does not really make sense to do this on mobile devices. For most problems, you'll even want to have decent GPU power for training which obviously can't be provided by an android device.
The way to get a tensorflow network onto your android device would be to train it locally and then ship the trained network to your device, which then only has to perform the evaluation and no training. Go to [Tensorflow Mobile](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/) for more insights on that.